# read syscall returns trash and reads more times than write syscall writes in a socket

Tags: c, sockets, system-calls

I want to implement a program that fork and exec a new process. The parent process will then write in a socket many times and the child process(execed) will read from the socket the whole data that  were sent by write. The problem is that some times when i run the program the child process reads 4501 times or more and prints trash, while parent process only writes 4500.
This does not happen all the time so i suspect there may be an unitialized variable somewhere.

parent process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>        
#include <sys/types.h>       
#include <sys/socket.h>      
#include <netinet/in.h>      
#include <netdb.h>           
#include <unistd.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>         
#include <ctype.h>           
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char * String;

void perror_exit(char *message);


int getSocketWrite(int portWrite){
    struct hostent *remWrite;
    struct sockaddr *serverptrWrite = NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in serverWrite;
    int sockWrite;
    serverptrWrite = (struct sockaddr*)&serverWrite;

    if ((sockWrite = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        perror_exit("socket");

    if (setsockopt(sockWrite, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)             //To reuse port if program exits.
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");


    char hostname[256];
    gethostname(hostname, 256);
    if ((remWrite = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) { 
       herror("gethostbyname"); 
       exit(1);
    }
    serverWrite.sin_family = AF_INET;       
    memcpy(&serverWrite.sin_addr, remWrite->h_addr, remWrite->h_length);
    serverWrite.sin_port = htons(portWrite);    

    while (connect(sockWrite, serverptrWrite, sizeof(serverWrite)) < 0);
    return sockWrite;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int             portWrite, sockWrite, i;
    int buffsize = 256;
    char            buf[buffsize];

    struct sockaddr_in serverWrite;
    struct sockaddr *serverptrWrite = NULL;
    struct hostent *remWrite = NULL;

    portWrite = 8080;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        execl("./server", "server");
        exit(1);
    }   
    else if(pid < 0){
        perror("error in fork");
    }
    
    sockWrite = getSocketWrite(portWrite);

    printf("Connecting to %s port %d\n", "Lenovo", portWrite);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4500; i++){
        memset(buf, 0, buffsize);
        strcpy(buf,"Test");
        write(sockWrite, buf, buffsize);
    }
    close(sockWrite);

}                

void perror_exit(char *message){
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

server.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>        
#include <sys/types.h>       
#include <sys/socket.h>      
#include <netinet/in.h>      
#include <netdb.h>           
#include <unistd.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>         
#include <ctype.h>           
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char * String;

void perror_exit(char *message);

int getSocketRead(int portRead){
    struct sockaddr_in serverRead;
    struct sockaddr *serverptrRead;
    int sockRead;
    serverptrRead = (struct sockaddr*)&serverRead;


    if ((sockRead = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (setsockopt(sockRead, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)             //To reuse port if program exits.
        perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");


    serverRead.sin_family = AF_INET;       
    serverRead.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverRead.sin_port = htons(portRead);      
    if (bind(sockRead, serverptrRead, sizeof(serverRead)) < 0){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(sockRead, 5) < 0) {
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Listening for connections to port %d\n", portRead);

    return sockRead;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int buffsize = 256;
    char buffer[buffsize];

    int portRead, sockRead, newsock;
    struct sockaddr_in serverRead, clientRead;
    socklen_t clientlen = 0;

    struct sockaddr *serverptrRead = NULL;
    struct sockaddr *clientptrRead = NULL;


// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    portRead = 8080;

    sockRead = getSocketRead(portRead);

    if ((newsock = accept(sockRead, clientptrRead, &clientlen)) < 0) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    int count = 0;
    int bytes = 0;
    memset(buffer, 0, buffsize);

    while ((bytes = read(newsock, buffer, buffsize)) > 0){
        count++;
        buffer[bytes] = '\0';
        printf("%s %d bytes\n", buffer, bytes);
    }
    close(sockRead);

    printf("Count = %d\n",count);
}



void perror_exit(char *message){
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I get the error roughly 1 out of 5 times i run the program.
The strange thing is that when i use sleep(1) every 500 times i write or so
the program seems to work just fine.

Comment: "*the child process reads 4501 times or more*". That is totally unsurprising behaviour. With stream based protocols like TCP each `read` is not guaranteed to receive exactly what was sent with a single `write`.

Comment: Is the total number of bytes read by the reader equal to the total number of bytes written by the writer?

Comment: How can i get the exactly what every write has sent? Is there a chance that I cant possibly do that?

Comment: No when i get the error read returns a random number of bytes but the bytes are always lower than the buffsize if i get the error.

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem finally but i cannot quite understand why this happens.
Sometimes read returns less bytes than given in argument and when it does I read the rest bytes and append them in my variable.
My question is, why does read() read less bytes than given. I also tried this with
pipes and read() always returned the expected result (bytes given to read)

Also why does write() always writes the expected number of bytes?

Comment: My kisses to my beloved Pourekka for helping me find the solution